# Positions of asteroids in heliocentric ecliptic (x,y,z) coordinates

Tags: orbital-mechanics, asteroid, jpl-horizons, ephemeris, ecliptic-plane

I would like to make positions of asteroids in heliocentric ecliptic (x,y,z) coordinates plot for a given date, like in the image below (Matsuoka N. Ryo (CC-BY 4.0)).

For that I need so-called state vectors (x, y, z positions in km or Astronomical units). I'm aware, that services like [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) can calculate them. Problem is... it can do that just for one asteroid at a time. Batch mode (via their API or E-mail) is also limited to few hundreds objects at best.

So question is - is there any readily available online service or software package, which can calculate these state vectors for asteroids using e.g. table with orbital elements, list of asteroids or something like that?

P. S. I've found [Skybot 3D](https://vo.imcce.fr/webservices/skybot3d/) service, made by Paris Observatory. Problem is that this service outputs state vectors (x,y,z) in equatorial coordinates system - not exactly what I'm looking for. Also, they're using their own asteroids database, which is slightly outdated.

[image: Matsuoka N. Ryo (CC-BY 4.0)]

Comment: FWIW, I'm a bit sceptical of the value of such plots because they exaggerate the density so much, as I mention here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/46928/16685